# Check if type can be an argument to boost::lexical_cast<string>

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost, template-meta-programming

I have the following traits class(`IsLexCastable`) to check if a type can be converted to a string by calling `boost::lexical_cast<string>`. It erroneously returns `true` for `vector<int>`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

namespace std
{
/// Adding to std since these are going to be part of it in C++14.
template <bool B, typename T = void>
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B, T>::type;
}

template <typename T, typename = void>
struct IsLexCastable : std::false_type
{
};

template <typename T>
struct IsLexCastable<T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::string, decltype(boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::declval<T>()))>::value> > : std::true_type
{
};

int main()
{
  vector<int> a = {1, 2, 3};
  //  cout << lexical_cast<string>(a) << endl;
  cout << IsLexCastable<decltype(a)>::value << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This program prints `1`, but `lexical_cast<string>(a)` results in a compile error. What is the right way to implement `IsLexCastable`?

(This was compiled with `g++48 -std=c++11`, and `boost 1.55.0`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your expression is not sufficient, as the `lexical_cast` function template takes everything and only reports errors via an internal `static_assert`. Instead test whether inserting the object into an `std::ostream` is valid:

```
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct IsLexCastable : std::false_type {};

// Can be extended to consider std::wostream as well for completeness
template <typename T>
struct IsLexCastable<T,
            decltype(void(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T>()))>
  : std::true_type {};
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e9f34665aacb9cb).
That requirement is called *OutputStreamable* by [**the documentation**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/conversion/lexical_cast.htm#lexical_cast), and the direct one imposed onto the source type.

---

#### Why did your implementation not work?

`decltype` only causes the **instantiation of the declaration** of a function template. The internal static assertion is triggered inside the definition of `lexical_cast` though, hence it cannot be used in SFINAE.

[temp.inst]/10:

> If a function template or a member function template specialization
>   **is used in a way that involves overload resolution, a declaration of the specialization is implicitly instantiated (14.8.3).**

Comment: This code may work, but it is actually worse in design than the OP's code because you are using implementation details of boost::lexical_cast. If you want to go this route you may as well just copy and paste the static assert that fails in boost::lexical_cast when you use it on an unsuitable type. The idea is to have code that tells whether boost::lexical_cast will work regardless of how it's implemented.

Comment: @NirFriedman This isn't some implementation detail but the actual requirement imposed by the library.

Comment: Thanks. Will try this out. Could you explain explain why the existing code failed? It has the call that your specialization has, but is wrapped in a metacall to is_same.

Comment: @Pradhan SFINAE works only in the immediate context. The call `boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(std::declval<T>())` is perfectly well formed in the immediate context because there is such a function template. Whether or not that function template would actually compile when instantiated doesn't matter.

Comment: @T.C. I think that explanation is irritating. The immediate context is more about the function declaration. Here the fact that the definitions isn't instantiated matters.

Comment: @Columbo But even if it instantiated the definition, it still won't work. You'd get a hard error instead.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, of course. My point is that the declaration of the function template `lexical_cast` doesn't contain anything that will either hard-error or cause a deduction failure. Even if there was some erroneous construct instantiated together with the declaration that  *wasn't in the immediate context of the declaration*, the instantiation would fail still. The immediate context only decides whether an error is a deduction failure or a hard one, but here there isn't any of both, so I can't see why you would mention the *immediate* context. :)

Comment: @Columbo Because only the validity of the immediate context of the function call expression is considered when deciding whether substitution succeeds :) (see, e.g., the the definition of `std::is_convertible` in [meta.rel]/p4 for this use of *immediate context*.)

Comment: This almost worked for me.  But, and I have to search very carefully still to find it, I have apparently got a << operator for ostream and std::vector<std::string> available but boost lexical_cast can't see it, likely for some namespace reasons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by Columbo answers the question, but I had problems adapting to to an input stream. My use case was that I wanted to call lexical_cast to convert from string to T. Boost offers has_right_shift and has_left_shift, which worked and should allow more flexibility for similar constructs.

```
template <typename T, typename=void>
struct IsLexCastable : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct IsLexCastable<T,
        typename std::enable_if<boost::has_right_shift<T>::value>::type>
  : std::true_type {};
```

Comment: Some details are missing here, for example there are more arguments to has_left_shift or has_right_shift, and if you look carefully, you'll notice that unless you specify that the LHS is an ostream or an istream, you're asking whether there's a shift operator, say << that results in a T after shifting a type T.  This isn't true for float or double, for example.  https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_right_shift.html